# Matching with large data set in R

Tags: r

I received [this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRlFi.jpg) from a professor of mine to solve in R.  Here's what I came up with:

```
buttons <- c(16,23,61,7,7,7,13,13,13,19,19,21,27,56,56,73,77,87,11,37,41)
combos<- NULL

for(bb in 1:80000){
  random<-sample(buttons,5,replace=FALSE)
  #A*B+C-D+E
  combos[bb]<-(random[1])*(random[2])+(random[3])-(random[4])+(random[5])
}

solutions<-c(917,134,1569,1649,1431,1622,233,2094,1072,915,
  1922,2437,2714,2491,1886,2812,426,1673,94,2139,2569,496,2249,1553,1580)

solutions %in% combos
```

What I think the code is doing:

1. Sampling 5 of the buttons on the machine without replacement.
2. Plugging those 5 numbers in the A*B+C-D+E formula.
3. Spitting out a final answer.  Repeat 80,000 times.
4. Last command should check all the outputs from the formula against the snack numbers in the machine and return a Boolean.

However, the Boolean comes back with 25 Trues when there should be 1 false.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I think your button vector should be `buttons<-c(16,23,61,7,7,7,13,13,13,19,19,21,27,56,56,73,77,97,11,37,41)`

Comment: Zooming in, it's definitely a `97` - http://i.stack.imgur.com/c11fl.png

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why you try to solve this with random sampling. You could never trust any answer other than that you can get all snacks. I'd use this:

```
buttons <- as.integer(buttons)
solutions <- as.integer(solutions)

#create all combinations of 5 buttons
combos <- t(combn(buttons, 5))
library(combinat)
#permute the combinations
tmp <- lapply(permn(1:5), function(i, solutions, combos) {
  #which solutions can be derived from the permuted combination?
  solutions[solutions %in% (combos[,i[1]] * 
                                combos[,i[2]] + 
                                combos[,i[3]] - 
                                combos[,i[4]] + 
                                combos[,i[5]])]
}, solutions = solutions, combos = combos)

#which solution can not be achieved?   
solutions[!(solutions %in% unlist(tmp))]
```

However, this doesn't give me a snack I can't get either. Maybe I'm misinterpreting the wording.

Comment: this guy claims to have solved it. Weird. https://www.localjobnetwork.com/a/t-vague-resumes-lead-to-hazy-prospects-au-murphy,-dave-articles-a886.html

Comment: I think the 18th element of the OP's button vector should be 97 rather than 87. Changing it and running your code gives 2437. (Also note that permn is from the `combinat` package)

Answer (score 2):

For starters remove the for loop. It is very inefficient:

```
random <- matrix(replicate(8e4, sample(buttons,5,replace=F)), ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
combos <-random[,1]*random[,2]+random[,3]-random[,4]+random[,5]
```

When I expand to one million combos, it matches all TRUE each time. There may be some confusion I'm not seeing in the question. Or your professor is a very cruel person.

Update:

I changed the buttons vector as mentioned in the comments:

```
solutions[!solutions %in% combos]
[1] 2437
```

Thanks, I can move on with my regularly scheduled life. Sampling isn't the best way, but problem solved.